# Оптимизация c# кода

Tags: c#

Как можно оптимизировать этот код?

```
int getID<T>(T senderClass, int ID) {
    switch (typeof(T).Name) {
        case "Counter"/* - имя класса*/:
            for (int i = 0; i < countersArray.Count /*list экземпляров класса*/; i++) {
                if (countersArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "Organization":
            for (int i = 0; i < organizationsArray.Count; i++) {
                if (organizationsArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "Representative":
            for (int i = 0; i < representativesArray.Count; i++) {
                if (representativesArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "Service":
            for (int i = 0; i < servicesArray.Count; i++) {
                if (servicesArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "Consumer":
            for (int i = 0; i < consumersArray.Count; i++) {
                if (consumersArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "ServiceByContract":
            for (int i = 0; i < servicesByContract.Count; i++) {
                if (servicesByContract[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "Contract":
            for (int i = 0; i < contractsArray.Count; i++) {
                if (contractsArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "Flat":
            for (int i = 0; i < flatsArray.Count; i++) {
                if (flatsArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case "User":
            for (int i = 0; i < usersArray.Count; i++) {
                if (usersArray[i].ID != ID)
                    continue;
                return i;
            }
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `countersArray` - эти коллекции в условиях, они разных типов?

Comment: и для чего нужен `senderClass` ?

Comment: Есть класс Counter, countersArray - List<Counter> countersArray = new List<Counter>(), все остальное по аналогии, senderClass я использую чтобы определять тип

Comment: Я вижу, что у ваших классов `Counter` и аналогов есть одинаковое поле ID - ваши классы реализуют какой то интерфейс с этим полем? Или классы вообще никак не пересекаются?

Comment: покажите также как вы используете ваш метод в вашем коде, для чего он?

Comment: Чтобы получить сведения из одного класса используется второй класс, например: Organization содержит в себе int ID и string Title, а Service - int ID, organizationID, name. Я использую этот метод, чтобы найти в List'е organizationsArray (содержащем экземпляры Organization) тот ID, который указан у меня в экземпляре servicesArray, т.е. organizationsArray[getID(servicesArray, servicesArray[i].organizationID)]

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос пожалуйста с более подробным описанием и желательно с примером кода (код более важен, чем любые описания)

Comment: И, кстати, если вы ищете индекс, тогда некорректно при отсутсвии элемента в массиве возвращать 0, так как 0 - указывает на нулевой элемент. Гораздо информативнее возвращать -1, так как в массиве элемента с индексом -1 быть не может.

Comment: Но вообще я попросил пример кода, так как скорее всего вы делаете что то не так, раз вам вообще понадобилась подобная конструкция как у вас

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете удалить ваш метод и заменить его на вызовы [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/03y7c6xy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Например:

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new MyClass() {ID = x}).ToArray();
var ind = Array.FindIndex(data, item=>item.ID == 3);
Console.WriteLine(ind);
```

Ожидаемый вывод

```
3
```

---

В случае, если вы работаете со списком, а не массивом, то разница небольшая

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new { ID = x }).ToList();
var ind = data.FindIndex(item => item.ID == 3);
Console.WriteLine(ind);
```

Ожидаемый вывод

```
3
```

Comment: судя по комментариям там `List<>`, поэтому [FindIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx) нужно у него брать :)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, добавил

Answer (score 0):

Судя по использованию свойства `Count`, все ваши `xxxxArray` на самом деле `List<T>`, следовательно для поиска индекса можно использовать его собственный метод `FindIndex`.

Если ваша задача просто сократить объем кода, то можно воспользоваться возможностями конструкции `switch` из C#7.

Кроме того, судя по использованию элементов списка, ваш `senderClass` сам содержит ID и можно избавиться от дополнительного параметра ID в методе.

Как уже написал [@tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873306/198316), когда элемент не найден использовать `0` в качестве результата не правильно, т.к. `0` является допустимым индексом любого массива, кроме пустого, следовательно такой ответ будет приводить к ошибкам в дальнейшем. Лучше использовать значение, которое ни когда не может быть допустимым индексом. `-1` как раз такое значение и является стандартным для всех поисковых методов в .NET, когда ищется именно индекс элемента.

Все выше описанное будет выглядеть, например, так:

```
int getID<T>(T senderClass) {
    switch (senderClass) {
        case Counter counter:
            return countersArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == counter.ID);
        case Organization organization:
            return organizationsArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == organization.ID);
        case Representative representative:
            return representativesArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == representative.ID);
        case Service service:
            return servicesArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == service.ID);
        case Consumer consumer:
            return consumersArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == consumer.ID);
        case ServiceByContract serviceByContract:
            return servicesByContract.FindIndex(item => item.ID == serviceByContract.ID);
        case Contract contract:
            return contractsArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == contract.ID);
        case Flat flat:
            return flatsArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == flat.ID);
        case User user:
            return usersArray.FindIndex(item => item.ID == user.ID);
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

---

Вообще конструкция сама по себе достаточно странная и наводит на мысли об ошибке проектирования, но не имея возможности увидеть где и как она используется, порекомендовать что либо еще практически невозможно.

Сразу можно отметить проблему данного метода. Так как на тип-параметр `T` нет ни каких ограничений, то невозможно понять почему именно элемент не был найден: потому что элемента нет в нужном списке или потому что метод применили к некорректному типу (вызвали с некорректным параметром типа). Это можно поправить возвращая в секции `default` какое-то другое отрицательное значение, например `-2`, что добавит информативности, однако простая ошибка: сущность добавили, а метод не исправили - все равно приведет к сложностям в диагностике и отладке.

Стоит так же выделить общий интерфейс у всех сущностей, как минимум явно напрашивается что-то типа:

```
interfase IHaveID
{
    int ID { get; set: }
}
```

Раз уж у всех ваших сущностей присутствует ID. За прочие интерфейсы ничего сказать не могу, недостаточно информации.

---

На правах телепата %):

Вероятно класс, к которому относится данный метод, используется как некий вариант единого репозитория. Если это верно, то стоит разделить его на отдельные репозитории для каждого типа сущности, естественно выделив и описав идентичный функционал интерфейсами.